# Can not persist an object with Id equals new BigDecimal(0)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, hql

The problem is that the cat object is not persisted if I set the id to 0 :

```
cat.setId(new BigDecimal(0));
session.save(cat);
```

It works with all the other numbers but not 0. Why ?

Comment: Are you flushing the session anywhere?

Comment: Does it work if put a scoping braces around your second example?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by flushing ? I open my session, open a transaction, commit it, then close the session at the end of my instructions.

Comment: This code samples are equivalent. Problem somewhere else.

Comment: Not quite, in the second case cat0, cat1, and cat2 stay in scope so each `Cat` has an additional reference.

Comment: What happens when you change your line session.save(cat); to session.save(cat.clone());

Comment: Sorry everyone, my bad. talex is right. The problem was else where. As I said in my answer, the real problem is when `id = new BigDecimal(0)`. Just forget about my question, it's a misunderstanding. But i should post a new question asking why `cat.setId(new BigDecimal(0));
session.save(cat);` does not persist the object in the table although there is no error in console.

Comment: Show us the relevant mappings.

Answer (score 0):

Well, sorry, in fact it works when I begin my loop from i = 1.

In fact, the real problem is that the cat object is not persisted if I set the id to 0 :

```
cat.setId(new BigDecimal(0));
session.save(cat);
```

If anyone knows why ? I should ask this in a new question.

Comment: You should better edit your question with above content.